# why is variable not used when clearly used in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a function that I enter a value into `var` and that outputs a value `var2` but it doesn't work.

I have tried making the code return the value with the return function but that didn't change anything.

```
def translate_num(var, var2):
    if var == 0:
        var2 = ""
        return var2
    if var == 1:
        var2 = "x"
        return var2
    if var == 2:
        var2 = "o"
        return var2
```

From here is just for a bit of context where I use the code # !not the full context

```
top_lef = game[0][0]
top_mid = game[0][1]
top_rig = game[0][2]
mid_lef = game[1][0]
mid_mid = game[1][1]
mid_rig = game[1][2]
bot_lef = game[2][0]
bot_mid = game[2][1]
bot_rig = game[2][2]
translate_num(top_lef, var1)
translate_num(top_mid, var2)
translate_num(top_rig, var3)
translate_num(mid_lef, var4)
translate_num(mid_mid, var5)
translate_num(mid_rig, var6)
translate_num(bot_lef, var7)
translate_num(bot_mid, var8)
translate_num(bot_rig, var9)
print(" ---  ---  --- \n| ", var1, "  || ", var2, "  || ", var3, "  | \n ---  ---  ---  \n ---  ---  ---  "
                                                                 "\n| ", var4, "  || ", var5, "  || ", var6,
      "  |\n ---  ---  --- \n ---  ---  ---"
      " \n| ", var7, "  || ", var8, "  || ", var9, "  |\n ---  ---  ---")
```

Pycharm puts an error saying the parameter `var2` is not used and that the function shadows `var2` from the outer scope.
I expect `var2`, `var3`, `var4` etc. to print to what the translate_num turns them into but they print as what I defined them as earlier in the code.

Comment: You can not *set* variables through parameters, so indeed if you `var2 = ""` in your function, it is *not* updated.

Comment: The closest working equivalent is `var1 = translate_num(top_lef)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expect `var2`, `var3`, `var4` etc. to print to what the translate_num turns them into but they print as what I defined them as earlier in the code.

You can not *set* the value of parameters. So the `var2 = ""` statement makes no sense. What you did was setting the *local* variable. But the variable at the *caller* side will not be updated. Imagine that you called the function with `translate_num(0, 5)`, then what would you expect your code to do? Assign a string to the `5` literal? What if you call it with `translate_num(0, 1+2)`, then you would assign it to a function call? It thus would result in a lot of odd behavior. Some programming languages allow such "pass-by-reference", like C++ and C# (with the `ref` and `out` parameters).

We thus should use the return value here to pass a result back and assign it to a variable:

```
def translate_num(i):
    return 'xo'[i-1:i]
```

Then you can set variables like:

```
var1 = translate_num(top_lef)
var2 = translate_num(top_mid)
var3 = translate_num(top_rig)
# ...
```